# Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'mydb/regimes' for key 'name'

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I am not an expert on databases but I'm modeling a database on mysqlworkbench 8.0.13 and when I try to run the script it breaks at this table(regimes). I can't figure out what KEY 'NAME' it is referring to. There's no key called name on this table.

I use this table's id as FK on two other tables. And both relationships are ONE-TO-MANY. But I don't think this should be a problem.
Can anyone please be so kind as to point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

**ERROR LOG:**

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1062: Duplicate entry 'mydb/regimes' for key 'name'
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`regimes` (
          `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
        COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

SQL script execution finished: statements: 49 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

**COMPANIES TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vacancies` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `manager_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `regime_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `vacancy_status_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `vacancy_type_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `area` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `exam_filename` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `workload` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `remuneration` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `soft_skills` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `level` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `specialty` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `skills` VARCHAR(2000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `help` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_vacancies_companies1_idx` (`company_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_vacancies_managers1_idx` (`manager_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_vacancies_vacancy_types1_idx` (`vacancy_type_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_vacancies_vacancy_statuses1_idx` (`vacancy_status_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_vacancies_regimes1_idx` (`regime_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vacancies_companies1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`companies` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vacancies_managers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`managers` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vacancies_vacancy_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vacancy_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vacancy_types` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vacancies_vacancy_statuses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vacancy_status_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vacancy_statuses` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_vacancies_regimes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`regime_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`regimes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**PROFESSIONAL_PROFILES**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`professional_profiles` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `talent_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `regime_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `vacancy_type_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `specialty` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `level` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `available` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `curriculum_filename` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `soft_skills` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `relocation` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `current_company` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_remuneration` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `intended_remuneration` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `remote` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `meeting_start` TIME NOT NULL,
  `meeting_end` TIME NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_professional_profiles_talents1_idx` (`talent_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_professional_profiles_vacancy_types1_idx` (`vacancy_type_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_professional_profiles_regimes1_idx` (`regime_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_professional_profiles_talents1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`talent_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`talents` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_professional_profiles_vacancy_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`vacancy_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`vacancy_types` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_professional_profiles_regimes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`regime_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`regimes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Error 1062: Duplicate entry ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_entry) is an error indicating you've tried to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (explicitly or implicitly) a row in a table using a key that already exists and that key column is defined as being unique in the table/index. This could be a primary key or another key that has been explicitly defined as unique. However, in your case, I suspect the duplicate entry results from trying to create an index with the same name twice. (I came to that conclusion because the index definitions themselves are also stored in a table, and the error you get refers to the name of your table as a value for the duplicate key.)

That said, I don't think the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `regimes` is what is causing this error. Your error log says you successfully ran 49 statements, and 1 statement resulted in an error. In your script, look for statements that create the `name` key. Do you have any [`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON regimes ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) or `ALTER TABLE regimes` statements? That would be something to look out for.

Comment: I solved it before reading your answer. But I guess I might have had a unique index or alter table as you pointed out. I used the auto generated script. I had to remove the table and run the script then add the table again and make the relationships and before run an alter table and everything went fine.